# Terraform: Pass json file contents to heredoc as json

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform to implement Azure Policies and wanted to know how I can take the json from our files that we fill variables with jinja templating and pass it as values to our terraform.

This is part of my code currently:

```
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "k8s_seccomp_governance" {
  name         = "k8s_seccomp_governance"
  description  = "Kubernetes cluster containers should only use allowed seccomp profiles"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = "Microsoft.Kubernetes.Data"
  display_name = "AMPS K8s Seccomp Governance"

  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "category": "Kubernetes",
    "version": "1.0.0"
    }

METADATA

  policy_rule = <<POLICY_RULE
    {
      "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "in": ["AKS Engine", "Microsoft.Kubernetes/connectedClusters", "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters"]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "constraintTemplate": "https://store.policy.core.windows.net/kubernetes/allowed-seccomp-profiles/v2/template.yaml",
          "constraint": "https://store.policy.core.windows.net/kubernetes/allowed-seccomp-profiles/v2/constraint.yaml",
          "excludedNamespaces": "[parameters('excludedNamespaces')]",
          "namespaces": "[parameters('namespaces')]",
          "values": {
            "allowedProfiles": "[parameters('allowedProfiles')]",
            "excludedContainers": "[parameters('excludedContainers')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The JSON present in the policy_rule block matches what is in the /policies/seccomp/seccomp_profile_rule.json file. I wanted to know or see how I can pass that json to the policy_rule block and keep formatting.

My file structure looks like this

```
.
├── policies
│   └── seccomp
│       ├── seccomp_parameters.json
│       └── seccomp_profile_rule.json
├── policy_assignments.tf
├── policy_definitions.tf
```

Comment: You can set:
`policy_rule = yamlencode(file("${path.module}/policies/seccomp/seccomp_profile_rule.json"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the contents directly with `file()` like this:

```
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "k8s_seccomp_governance" {
  name         = "k8s_seccomp_governance"
  description  = "Kubernetes cluster containers should only use allowed seccomp profiles"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = "Microsoft.Kubernetes.Data"
  display_name = "AMPS K8s Seccomp Governance"

  metadata = jsonencode({
    category = "Kubernetes"
    version = "1.0.0"
  })

  policy_rule = file("policies/seccomp/seccomp_profile_rule.json") # or maybe file("${path.module}/seccomp/seccomp_profile_rule.json")
}
```

Notice that you can also avoid the clunky HEREDOC syntax by putting your code in an object and jsonencoding it like I did with the `metadata` parameter.

Comment: Awesome I will try that tomorrow and let you know. I was having problems finding this in their documentation.

Also I like using that jsonencoding like that, makes it more readable. Thanks